# Getting Error -1073741819 (0xC0000005) - Using matrix after a specific number

Tags: c, windows, matrix, malloc, stack-overflow

So my task is to write a program that simulates covid-19 sickness chances. It's a University task, not a job.

I've tried to comment my code to be readable for anyone.

My main problem is, when I change the value of L to a number higher than 80 for example, I'll get error code: -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

The expected number by the teacher would be 150, so a matrix of 150*150 = 22500

Basically what the code does:
It finds a random row and column = random person, and checks if he is sensitive to the virus (number=0) or if he is already sick (number=1)..

If he is sensitive, we generate a random number and we compare that to the number of Gamma, or Beta, depends if we want to heal him, or get him sick.

For my reviews on stackoverflow, I found out that I might have to make it a dynamic matrix, but I have no idea how to do that, since when I trited to change it to something like:

```
int *nepesseg= (int *)malloc(L*L* sizeof(int));
```

I just got more errors, since I don't know how to refer to the matrix's elements anymore, etc.

I'm currently using Code::Blocks + GNU GCC Compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>


#define L 70 // IF THIS NUMBER IS MORE, LIKE 100, I GET "-1073741819 (0xC0000005)" Error code


int main()
{


    srand(time(NULL));
    int day=365, randomPersonRow=0,randomPersonColumn=0;
    double beta=0.7,gamma=0.1,odds=0.0; //Gamma = healing chance, Beta = chance for getting sick
    int SensitiveCount,SickCount,HealedCount;



    int population[L][L];

    SensitiveCount=(L*L)-1;SickCount=1;HealedCount=0;


    int i,j,v,u;

    for(i=0; i<L; i++) {
      for(j=0;j<L;j++) {
        population[i][j]=0;
      }
    }
    randomPersonRow=(rand()%L);
    randomPersonColumn=(rand()%L);
    population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn]=1; //first sick person - generated random


    FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("result.dat", "w");



    for(v=1; v<=day; v++){ //365 days
        for(u=0;u<=L*L;u++){ //1 day
            randomPersonRow=(rand()%L); //Find a random person to see if he is sick or not
            randomPersonColumn=(rand()%L); //Find a random person to see if he is sick or not
            //for(i=0; i<L; i++) {
              //for(j=0;j<L;j++) {
                if(population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn]==0){ //0 means he is Sensitive, and not sick or healed yet

                    if(population[randomPersonRow+1][randomPersonColumn]==1){ // If he meets a sick person in his "matrix" - 4 chance(up, down, left, right)
                        odds=((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                        if(odds<=beta){
                            population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn]=1; // He is getting sick, if he has been in contact with a sick person
                            SensitiveCount=SensitiveCount-1;SickCount=SickCount+1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn+1]==1){
                        odds=((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                        if(odds<=beta){
                            population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn]=1; // He is getting sick, if he has been in contact with a sick person
                            SensitiveCount=SensitiveCount-1;SickCount=SickCount+1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(population[randomPersonRow-1][randomPersonColumn]==1){
                        odds=((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                        if(odds<=beta){
                            population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn]=1; // He is getting sick, if he has been in contact with a sick person
                            SensitiveCount=SensitiveCount-1;SickCount=SickCount+1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn-1]==1){
                        odds=((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                        if(odds<=beta){
                            population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn]=1; // He is getting sick, if he has been in contact with a sick person
                            SensitiveCount=SensitiveCount-1;SickCount=SickCount+1;
                        }
                    }



                }
                if(population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn]==1){ // 1 = If the random person is sick

                    odds=((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                    if(odds<=gamma){
                        population[randomPersonRow][randomPersonColumn]=2; // He is healed now, if the odds are less then the random gamma value.
                        SickCount=SickCount-1;HealedCount=HealedCount+1;
                    }

                }
            //}
        //}
      }
      if(fp!=NULL){
                fprintf(fp,"%d; %d; %d; %d; \n",v,SensitiveCount,SickCount,HealedCount); // writing to file
            }else{
                printf("Error!");
            }
    }



    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception `0xC0000005` is related to a memory violation on MS-WIN systems, which I think you're using.

About the code I don't see any formal error. Anyway it is not a good idea to allocate large array as automatic variables, move the declaration outside of `main` function, or prefix it with `static` modifier as in `static int population[L][L];`.

In any case it is really strange to trigger a memory exception with `L` up to 500 on my system with 1MB of allocated stack space.

The problem can come from the compiler you're using that allocates too small stack space.

Comment: The array size is 4 * 500 * 500 , that’s a lot of stack

Comment: @pm100 I have the same thinking. I made a test on my system and can allocate up to 500 elements before crash with 1MB stack.But 150 Elements should be ok. Which compiler is he using?

Comment: I'm using GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: @AranySandor does it work using `static` qualifier? Anyway it is still strange. Even compiling for 64bits long int's you shuld be allowed to manage a 150*150*8=180kB, not a big issue for a standard 1MB stack allocation...

Comment: Yes it does work when I use a static qualifier, so thank you, it solved my problem, however it's strange indeed.
Thanks again!

Comment: @AranySandor You can try forcing the stack size using `--stack,4194304` to set stack to 4Mb. Anyway please accept the answer to don't let it swinging still open.